# Oracle procedure creation warning message

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, oracle9i

Am using the below code to create a procedure in oracle.This is compiled with warning message

> Warning: compiled but with compilation errors.

I can't able to fix this issue. Please help me to fix this issue.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_get_discount_master(In_value IN float) IS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_discount_master
        (fld_value)
    VALUES
        (In_value);
    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
END sp_get_discount_master;
```

Comment: type this in your console (SQLPlus): SHOW ERRORS; and let us know what errors that reports.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of items in your code that i dislike.

1. Prefixing the procedure name with "sp_"
2. Prefixing the parameter name with "in_"
3. Using the data type float, which is imprecise in arithmetical operations
4. USING UPPERCASE FOR YOUR CODE when lower case is easier to read.
5. Use of "when others", which will cause any runtime failure to be hidden from you.

Carry on.

Comment: That is hardly an answer to the question.

Comment: Indeed it is not, but I'm taking an holistic view of the situation. Without the answer to @jachguate's comment there's little that can be done anyway.